Beamer Lyx, problems with second slide without seperator
I am trying to create a second slide using beamer in lyx. I have tried everything, pressing enter to insert seperator, or using seperator-insert command... nothing works. Once I click on Frame and enter frametitle then I cant create a new frame environment.
So I want to try the SWP solution to lyx. Using tex field
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
and then add things in between
I was wondering, is there a way to create a short cut that will automatically insert a custom frame each time i press it.
for example if I press shift+b+f then can i get something like
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aaaaa}
\begin{itemize}
\item fghgfhfg
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
I have tried command sequence but it did not work. I would appreciate any help. The reason i use lyx is that with short cuts it is very easy to write long math equations, easier than writing actually.
